# Ng-repeat on generic element

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem. I would like to make a ng-repeat on a different json depending on the call.

I want to do this: When the call is made on elementHeaderATMT
I display the following code

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                            <tr ng-repeat="element in elementsHeaderATMT">
                                <th>{{ element.transportLine }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.station }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.transformer }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.park }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.lineMT }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.section }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.CD }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.transformerCdCm }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.element }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.type }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="element in elementsDataATMT">
                                <td>{{ element.transportLine }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.station }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.transformer }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.park }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.lineMT }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.section }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.CD }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.transformerCdCm }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.element }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.type }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

otherwise this..
but if I want to do this automatically What should I do

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                            <tr ng-repeat="element in elementsHeaderBT">
                                <th>{{ element.CD }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.Cuadro }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.Salida }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.type }}</th>
                                <th>{{ element.element }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="element in elementsDataATMT">
                                <td>{{ element.CD }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.Cuadro }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.Salida }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.type }}</td>
                                <td>{{ element.element }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

My Json is this

```
{
"ATMT": {

    "header": [{

        "transportLine": "Linea Transporte",
        "station": "Estracion",
        "transformer": "Trafo",
        "park": "Parque",
        "lineMT": "Linea MT",
        "section": "Tramo",
        "CD": "CD",
        "transformerCdCm": "Trafo CD/CM",
        "element": "Elemento",
        "type": "Tipo"

    }],

    "data": [{

        "transportLine": "",
        "station": "ABRERA",
        "transformer": "",
        "park": "25",
        "lineMT": "AGUAS1",
        "section": "",
        "CD": "LL...",
        "transformerCdCm": "",
        "element": "T-1",
        "type": "DIS_MAN_CD"

    }]
},

"BT": {

    "header": [{

        "CD": "CD",
        "picture": "Cuadro",
        "departure": "Salida",
        "type": "Tipo",
        "element": "Elemento BT"


    }],

    "data": [{

        "CD": "C100446",
        "picture": "11",
        "departure": "01",
        "type": "",
        "element": ""

    }]
}
```

}

and my controller is this

```
                    $scope.elementsHeaderATMT = response.ATMT.header;
                    $scope.elementsDataATMT = response.ATMT.data;

                    $scope.elementsHeaderBT = response.BT.header;
                    $scope.elementsDataBT = response.BT.data;
```

sorry for my poor English but I hope I was clear
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your idea, you like iterate over the key, value tuple in the json.
This would be suitable here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in elementsDataATMT ">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Key return 0. this is the code result:
0{"transportLine":"" ,"station":"ABRERA","transformer":"","park":"25","lineMT":"AGUAS1","section":"","CD":"LL...","transformerCdCm":"","element":"T-1","type":"DIS_MAN_CD"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) on both tables with a variable you set in the controller:

```
<table class="table" ng-if="elementHeaderATMTCalled">
<table class="table" ng-if="!elementHeaderATMTCalled">
```

And in the controller, each time you make your call, you update that variable.

```
$scope.elementHeaderATMTCalled = true; // or false
```